# Django-rest-framework, nested objects in Serializers

Tags: serialization, nested, django-rest-framework

I would like to have a nested object inside a serializer instead of just the foreignkey (or url).
As [this documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#nested-relationships) says, I just had to specify the serializer class of the nested object in the parent serializer:

```python
# Models

class NestedSample(models.Model):
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Sample(models.Model):
    thing = models.BooleanField()
    nested = models.ForeignKey(NestedSample)

# Serializers

class NestedSampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = api_models.NestedSample

class SampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    nested = NestedSampleSerializer() # HERE!

    class Meta:
        model = api_models.Sample

# Views

class NestedSampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = api_models.NestedSample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = api_serializers.NestedSampleSerializer

class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = api_models.Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = api_serializers.SampleSerializer
```

This works very well when I get the objects, but it is not possible to create (=`POST`) `Sample` objects anymore, I get the error:

```
{u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid data']}
```

I tried to overwrite the `create` method in the viewset to get the object using the pk:

```python
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = api_models.Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = api_serializers.SampleSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        request.DATA['nested'] = get_object_or_404(api_models.NestedSample, pk=request.DATA['nested'])
        return super(SampleViewSet, self).create(request)
```

But it doesn't work as well.

Any idea?

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883678/django-rest-framework-different-depth-for-post-put) I can relate with which of course solves the problem but do not let me expose the full nested object, so back to the beginning.

Thanks,

Comment: You shouldn't need that overridden `create` to populate your request data with a NestedSample instance, the PK string should work by itself.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686888/how-to-implement-nested-models-routes/23696134#23696134

Answer (score 3):

Can you confirm that you're sending a JSON encoded request - i.e. the request has the content type set to JSON ?
If not, the post is most probably send using form format which doesn't support nested.

Comment: No, I just send the values using the basic format, I don't know its name: `?thing=1&nested=2` and I send the `pk` of an existing nested object, I don't want to create a new one.

Comment: Using the rest_framework.test.APIClient in my tests fixed this for me. (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing#apiclient)

Comment: This is the first mention that I found of getting the encoding correct at test time - thanks @XavierOrdoquy ... Adding `format='json'` to my `client.post` request at test time fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two solutions to this problem. I prefer the first one.

First solution:

Use a django model form to create objects. Override the create and update methods. A sample create method:

```
def create(self, request):
    form = SampleForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return Response(dict(id=instance.pk), status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(form.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this way you can create Sample objects with any kind of validation you like.

Second solution:

Override get_serializer_class method and return serializer class based on request method. Define two serializers one for post and put and one for list and retrieve.